# Securing a http connection

Tags: security, ssl, https, ssl-certificate

I'm looking for some info about securing a website. The website is actually a kind of management console that can be accesses through a web browser. The console is currently only available on the internal network, but I want to make it accessible through the internet, only for some specific users/devices.

The first problem I faced is that the management console didn't provide authentication at all. To overcome that problem, I've installed apache, which I use as a (reverse?)proxy and in which I enabled basic authentication, so now I have to enter a username and password before I can access the console.

The thing that I want to do next is to prevent the username and password to be send over the line as plain text (I assume that's whats happening now). I think I have to make it a https connection for that, but I find so much information about that so that I'm a bit lost on how to continue. Can I make this work with self signed certificates or do I need to buy certificates somewhere?

Comment: Simplest is probably to purchase one, that way it should work on most/all types of clients transparently. Self signed certs are especially a hassle if you need to distribute them to a variety of mobile clients. If the clients can't validate the certificate by either knowing the certificate authority or your self signed cert, there basically is no security against man-in-the-middle attacks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right about securing passwords through https. I would suggest redirecting everything on your server through https, following [this article](http://www.sslshopper.com/apache-redirect-http-to-https.html).

I would suggest testing the whole solution without buying anything. Buying a certificate means that it would be bound to your server. I suppose that when you develop your solution, you use a development server. If you buy a certificate for your development server, then you would have to buy another one for your production server. Therefore, I would use a self-signed certificate for development and when the application is ready to go public, then I would buy a certificate recognized by all browsers.

In order to create a self-signed certificate you could follow [this tutorial](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/392099-creating-self-signed-ssl-certificates-for-apache-on-linux) supposing you work on linux, or [this tutorial](http://rubayathasan.com/tutorial/apache-ssl-on-windows/) supposing you work on windows.

Hope I helped!